# Photoshop: how to replace a color with a specific new one

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I have an image I'm just copy and pasting into Photoshop from another screen/web browser. It's a greyscale clipart-style line drawing on a white background. I want to change ALL the white pixels in the image to another color (a specific RGB value), including the white pixels inside the drawing.

The `Replace Color` command appeared promising, but I can't enter an RGB or even absolute HSB value.

So: how do I do this, either using Replace Color or another approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case, instead of “replacing” selected color range, I'd rather add a layer filled with specific color below your clipart and changed clipart layer blending mode to “Multiply”. IMHO it's much easier than just “replacing white”, allows you to easily change background color without reselecting background and—finally—will make dark lines properly blend into background.

As for filling layer with specific color, you can create “Solid Color” “Fill Layer” (recommended) or create empty layer and filling it with foreground/background color (IIRC there should be such actions in “Edit” menu, there are also keyboard shortcuts to do that). The latter method works also with selections.

Comment: Thanks! That worked nicely. It's almost as good as making the white background transparent. Based on my web research, it seemed doing that is a hassle -- or not?

Comment: Glad it worked for you :). Well… hassle… I think each new technique seems a bit of a hassle at first but it's becoming quite obvious in time.

Comment: Another thing came to my mind recently: take a look e.g. at http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/blend-if/. Instead of “selecting white” or changing layer blending mode, you can also use “Blend If” sliders in “Blending Options”. Of course “coloring” layer should be below in this case too.

Answer (score 2):

Select > color range ... or the magic wand with a narrow selection range (and 'contiguous' unchecked) should do the trick pretty quickly.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I now have the white bits selected using the Select > Color Range tool. Now how do I change the color of that selection to a specific RBG color value, or a color I pick using the eyedropper? I've tried Image > Adjustments > Hue/Saturation, but that only has +/- HSB adjustment, not absolute color choices.

Comment: @Ghopper21 Edit > Fill… (shift+F5) to fill any selection with any colour. You can do it on a new layer to avoid destructive editing of the original too.